# TV datafeed is not suported in Backtesting.py?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, back-testing

I'm trying use Trading View data feed for my backtest analysis and i got an issue that backtesting.py only need OHLC and (optionally) Volume for analysis, and I come here ask for help for the issue:

```
class RsiOscillator(Strategy):




ma_bound = ma
rsi_window = rsi

# Do as much initial computation as possible
def init(self):
    self.rsi = self.I(ta.rsi, pd.Series(self.data.Close), self.rsi_window)

# Step through bars one by one
# Note that multiple buys are a thing here
def next(self):
    if crossover(self.rsi > ma_bound):
        self.position.open()
    elif crossover(self.ma_bound, self.rsi):
        self.buy()

bt = Backtest(petr4_data, RsiOscillator, cash=10_000)
stats = bt.run()
bt.plot()
```

> ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) Cell In[48], line 22 19
> elif crossover(self.ma_bound, self.rsi): 20 self.buy()
> ---> 22 bt = Backtest(petr4_data, RsiOscillator, cash=10_000, commission=.002) 23 stats = bt.run() 24 bt.plot()
>
> File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\backtesting\backtesting.py:1067, in
> Backtest.init(self, data, strategy, cash, commission, margin,
> trade_on_close, hedging, exclusive_orders) 1065 raise ValueError('OHLC
> data is empty') 1066 if len(data.columns.intersection({'Open', 'High',
> 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'})) != 5:
> -> 1067 raise ValueError("data must be a pandas.DataFrame with columns " 1068 "'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', and (optionally) 'Volume'")
> 1069 if data[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']].isnull().values.any():
> 1070 raise ValueError('Some OHLC values are missing (NaN). ' 1071
> 'Please strip those lines with df.dropna() or ' 1072 'fill them in
> with df.interpolate() or whatever.')
>
> ValueError: data must be a pandas.DataFrame with columns 'Open',
> 'High', 'Low', 'Close', and (optionally) 'Volume'

The DF that i'm trying to use comes with datetime, OHLC and volume, I try to reorder or delete but the py still not accept.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when I was using modin.pandas instead of pandas. It is raised because this assertion yields False:

```
len(petr4_data.columns.intersection({'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume'})) != 5
```

Kindly execute these three statements and post each output here:

```
petr4_data.head()
print(petr4_data.dtypes)
print(type(petr4_data))
```